# c# json as not pulling data

Tags: c#, httpclient

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to pull some data but it doesn't parse as json, how can i do this, is there anyone who can throw it as code?

my code

```
  var begendurum = await client.GetStringAsync("https://eu.mspapis.com/profilegeneratedcontent/v2/profiles/" + gonderilecek + "/games/j68d/content");

                var jsonContent = JObject.Parse(begendurum);

                var sondurum = jsonContent[0]["id"].ToString();

                Console.Write(sondurum);
```

json body:

```
[{
"addedDate": "2021-03-21T09:15:36.6030275+00:00",
"complexity": 0,
"defaultSnapshotType": "snapshot",
"gameId": "j68d",
"id": "4037c9a6ef8e45f18094bfaa570d2977",
"lastEditedDate": "2021-03-21T09:15:36.8996736+00:00",
"lifecycleStatus": "Active",
"owner": "00037853cc134d4cbe970b6aedebe21d",
"participantIds": ["00037853cc134d4cbe970b6aedebe21d"],
"privacyStatus": "Public",
"publishedDate": "2021-03-21T09:15:36.8996736+00:00",
"type": "WAYD",
"resources": [{
    "id": "profiles/00037853cc134d4cbe970b6aedebe21d/j68d/wayd/4037c9a6ef8e45f18094bfaa570d2977/437e53a188414c7b96058a15790f660d",
    "type": "PgcV1"
}]
}, {
"addedDate": "2021-03-21T09:13:06.0389296+00:00",
"complexity": 0,
"defaultSnapshotType": "snapshot",
"gameId": "j68d",
"id": "55335bca6496404587f90e0d4a1adb24",
"lastEditedDate": "2021-03-21T09:13:06.2070069+00:00",
"lifecycleStatus": "Active",
"owner": "00037853cc134d4cbe970b6aedebe21d",
"participantIds": ["00037853cc134d4cbe970b6aedebe21d"],
"privacyStatus": "Public",
"publishedDate": "2021-03-21T09:13:06.2070069+00:00",
"type": "WAYD",
"resources": [{
    "id": "profiles/00037853cc134d4cbe970b6aedebe21d/j68d/wayd/55335bca6496404587f90e0d4a1adb24/37d1d9eb02a24842bd3f10b50bca2213",
    "type": "PgcV1"
}]
}, {
"addedDate": "2021-03-21T08:58:37.6752327+00:00",
"complexity": 0,
"defaultSnapshotType": "snapshot",
"gameId": "j68d",
"id": "aa1f7e060c88418f9c7815665922d304",
"lastEditedDate": "2021-03-21T08:58:38.1642128+00:00",
"lifecycleStatus": "Active",
"owner": "00037853cc134d4cbe970b6aedebe21d",
"participantIds": ["00037853cc134d4cbe970b6aedebe21d"],
"privacyStatus": "Public",
"publishedDate": "2021-03-21T08:58:38.1642128+00:00",
"type": "WAYD",
"resources": [{
    "id": "profiles/00037853cc134d4cbe970b6aedebe21d/j68d/wayd/aa1f7e060c88418f9c7815665922d304/6333938ca3114a56bcb150cd7b1d9bd5",
    "type": "PgcV1"
}]
}, {
"addedDate": "2021-03-21T08:19:08.0288282+00:00",
"complexity": 0,
"defaultSnapshotType": "full",
"gameId": "j68d",
"id": "083b37b1c18c49228771e16183a88436",
"lastEditedDate": "2021-03-21T08:19:08.0288282+00:00",
"lifecycleStatus": "Active",
"owner": "00037853cc134d4cbe970b6aedebe21d",
"participantIds": [],
"privacyStatus": "Public",
"publishedDate": "2021-03-21T08:19:08.0288282+00:00",
"type": "avatar",
"resources": [{
    "id": "profiles/00037853cc134d4cbe970b6aedebe21d/j68d/avatar/083b37b1c18c49228771e16183a88436/ad8ff2491104489da5a98ea31ee02fe4",
    "type": "PgcV1"
}, {
    "id": "profiles/00037853cc134d4cbe970b6aedebe21d/j68d/avatar/083b37b1c18c49228771e16183a88436/9e0298665ae6446ab80f8fe9bfb43a54.png",
    "type": "face"
}, {
    "id": "profiles/00037853cc134d4cbe970b6aedebe21d/j68d/avatar/083b37b1c18c49228771e16183a88436/6caeef28c90846bda5cf9a71470c2be0.png",
    "type": "full"
}]
}]
```

Comment: There is probably an exception thrown, because you are calling `JObject.parse()` on a string that contains an array. Try `JArray.parse()`

Comment: can you write the code please? @derpirscher

Comment: replace `JObject.parse()` with `JArray.parse()`

Answer (score 0):

Use  Json.Parse(begendurum);

```
var begendurum = await client.GetStringAsync("https://eu.mspapis.com/profilegeneratedcontent/v2/profiles/" + gonderilecek + "/games/j68d/content");

var jsonContent = Json.Parse(begendurum);

var sondurum = jsonContent[0]["id"].ToString();

Console.Write(sondurum);
```